# Python - stitch images back together after slicing

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, python-imaging-library

I have a directory of image patches that are all the same size (33x33), the images are ordered so that the first 7 images are row 1, then the next 7 images are row 2, etc. I'm currently trying to reconstruct the original image using the 33x33 patches, but I am having trouble with the rows/cols organization. Any help with this is much appreciated! Here is my code for splitting the image into tiles:

```
def split_images():
    img_arr = []
    for image_path in image_paths:
        image = cv2.imread(image_path, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)  # read in image
        for i in range(0, image.shape[0], 33):  # loop through height-wise pixels of image, striding by 33
            for j in range(0, image.shape[1], 33):  # loop through width-wise pixels of image, striding by 33
                images = image[i:i + 33, j:j + 33, :]  # creating label image from h,w pixel to 33 pixels to the right and down
                img_arr.append(images)  # create list from label images
                # write images
                cv2.imwrite(f"../outputs/subimages/subimage{i}_{j}.png", images)


    return {"images": img_arr}
```

This splits the image into the aforementioned 33x33 tiles, but stitching them back together is where I'm having trouble. I can currently stitch the image back together in one long row, but I'm unsure of how to stitch the images back into their original order. This is my current stitching code:

```
def merge_images():
    space_between_row = 10
    new_image_path = 'result.jpg'
    im_dirs = glob.glob('../outputs/subimages')

    # get sorted list of images
    im_path_list = [[path.join(p, f) for f in sorted(listdir(p))] for p in im_dirs]

    # open images and calculate total widths and heights
    im_list = []
    total_width = 0
    total_height = 0
    for path_list in im_path_list:
        images = list(map(Image.open, path_list))
        widths, heights = zip(*(i.size for i in images))
        total_width = max(total_width, sum(widths))
        total_height += max(heights)
        im_list.append(images)

    # concat images
    new_im = Image.new('RGB', (total_width, total_height))
    y_offset = 0
    for images in im_list:
        x_offset = 0
        max_height = 0
        for im in images:
            new_im.paste(im, (x_offset, y_offset))
            x_offset += im.size[0]
            max_height = max(im.size[1], max_height)
        y_offset = y_offset + max_height + space_between_row

    # show and save
    new_im.show()
    new_im.save(new_image_path)
```

Comment: Stitch images row by row (np.hstack). Then stick all the rows together in a vertical stack (np.vstack).  Or use ImageMagick montage to do it all in one command.

Comment: I did give ImageMagick a shot, and it didn't quite achieve what I was looking for. I am working on the vstack/hstack method now. I'm having trouble with it because all my images are in one directory rather than separate directories that contain each row. Do you happen to have a code snippet I could look at?

Comment: No, not for the way you number them. But if you are interested in using ImageMagick, then you might look at my overlapcrop, script (with 0 overlap) to tile them and save as PNG. Then ImageMagick will put them all back together in the order they were cropped exactly as the input automatically using `convert yourimagename*.png -background black -flatten result.png` Since with PNG, ImageMagick stores the tile offsets in the file header.

Comment: Or with your files as is, if they are listed alphabetically in your directory, then you can put them together with ImageMagick command line command `montage yourimagename*.png -tile 7x7 -geometry +0+0 result.png` Assuming you have 7 rows. If not change the -tile argument appropriately to 7xN for N rows.

Comment: Or if they are listed alphabetically in your directory, then you can just take 7 files at a time and do np.hstack() and save to a different name or directory. Then do np.vstack() on all the rows from the np.hstack().

Comment: `np.block([[im11, im12, im13, im14, im15, im16, im17], [im21, im22, im23, ...]])` -- and I would recommend using either opencv or PIL for both reading and writing, but no mixing.